# sql query and ABAP keyword 'WITH'

Tags: common-table-expression, abap, hana

In SQL I can do something like this:

```
Declare @lv_count
Set @lv_count = ( Select Count(*) From BKPF where)
If @lv_count > 0
Begin
    sql_query1
Else
    sql_query2
End
```

ABAP:

```
WITH +ttassignment AS (
     SELECT financialinstrumentassignment
     FROM +ttRANL_FLOW_S
     WHERE financialinstrumentassignment <> @lv_empty_char
     GROUP BY financialinstrumentassignment )
```

How can I do this?

```
+ttresult AS (
If Count(+ttassignment) > 0
    Select * from +ttquery1
Else
    Select * from +ttquery2
EndIf )
```

Comment: But why you are trying to use `with` here and perform `count` inside `if` statement, not a query itself? These queries are different. Just use `select count( distinct financialinstrumentassignment ) FROM +ttRANL_FLOW_S WHERE financialinstrumentassignment <> @lv_empty_char  into @count_variable`

Comment: are you doing this on pure HANA? or on ABAP on HANA? are CDS allowed?

Comment: @Suncatcher, ABAP on HANA and CDS is allowed.

Comment: @astentx, As can i understand cte is new abap technology that can provide more performance and use only one hits to database.
[https://archer4sap.com/sap-abap-7-51_v1/cte-common-table-expressions](https://archer4sap.com/sap-abap-7-51_v1/cte-common-table-expressions)
My idea use cte as maximum as it possible.     
.  
As for me cte looks like stored procedures in sql and it's more clear for me then select endselect/loop/movie correspondents, and performances increes.
.
I trying understanding limits for cte.

Comment: @AlGraf CTE doesn't provide any performance benefits by itself. It is a language construct, that allows you to write more clear code and reduce roundtrips. But SQL statement cannot have conditional branches, it is always executed as is. Because the first step is a compilation and preparation of execution plan, there's no any data processing at this point to decide what should be executed

Comment: Did you know that you can embed SQLScript in ABAP using [ABAP-Managed Database Procedures](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/01/22/abap-managed-database-procedures-introduction/)?

Comment: @AlGraf I still won't post that as an answer, because it's a workaround and not an actual answer to the question you asked.

Comment: @Philipp, I think there is no way to answer to my question, but your way can solved my issue too. Anyway thank you.